# ASP.NET Web API, Creating a User, Is this a suitable method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I am creating a ASP.NET Web API for my mobile apps to consume.

However I will need to store information about a user i.e points or details

So, Is it a suitable option to use the User ID from Microsoft.Identity as an identifier in a different database?
Currently users are created in a local Database file automatically created by ASP. I would like to store other data regarding this user but Microsot.Identity is limited, so can I link to a different database and link the user?

Here is my scenario:

**Sign-up**

1. User Signs up at /api/register
2. Server creates a record in seperate database for the new user
   storing the
3. Microsoft.Identity UserID (Along with other user details maybe)

**Log-in**

1. User logs in at ***/token*** to recive there auth token.
2. Token is sent with request to get user deatils: ***GET /user***.
3. On the server I user user.getID to get the ID of that user.
4. Check the ID with a record in a different database..
5. Return the details linked to that user ID.

Comment: Having been through the pain up upgrading a website's login system twice... Asp.Net Membership, SimpleMembership (why???) then Identity, the concept of keeping the user database separated from the business database and linking users between them by means of a common token is what I opted for too. I'd be careful of choosing any ID token that is specific to Asp.Net Identity. We don't have usernames... all logins are done by email address/3rd party login, so we opted for using the username field as the place to store the common token that links users in one db to users in the other.